# Timer which can be called from a class and form both

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have a simple WinForm application. The main entry point of the application is mainForm. I am using a Timer on the form and the timer interval is being set to 2000ms. The Tick event of the Timer is as below,

```
Public myValue as Integer = 100

Private Sub myTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles myTimer.Tick
    If myValue = 0 Then
        myTimer.Enabled = False
    Else
        myValue = myValue -1
    End If
End Sub
```

The timer is being called at the start of the application when mainForm is loaded. Now myValue is a global variable and here for the purpose of simplicity I have used this otherwise it is replaced by some process count mechanism which is not required to be explained here.

I am able to use this approach as long as I am using Windows.Forms.Timer placed on some specific Form. I have two more scenarios in which this approach fails.

1 - I have to use the same functionality on some other form and for this currently I am using a separate Timer on another Form and it has its own Tick event.

2 - I have to use the same functionality from another module/class and I am unable to achieve this because for this to work I require a Form.

Now for a start I have looked into Threading.Timer. The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to wait for Threading.Timer to finish as the control goes to next line after Threading.Timer is called. I am not sure whether this can be done with the help of WaitHandle or not. Also I have read that Threading.Timer creates a separate Thread for each of its Tick. This seems like an overkill in my simple scenario.

I just want to use the Timer functionality without the need of Form. Also I could create the similar functionality using a Do Loop with Thread.Sleep inside it but unless I am sure that my Timer functionality is not going to work in other situations I am going to stick to my Timer approach.

Comment: there is also a `System.Timers.Timer`.  given some of what you wrote it might make sense to use a class to do the timing independent of either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see ... If thats the case, you should really create a second thread that runs a loop. That thread has some exiting parameters that indicates that operation is completed and the Thread itself is set to Isbackground = false.

However, you could also do this ...

```
Imports System.Timers

Public Class Main

    Private Shared WithEvents m_oTimer As Timers.Timer = Nothing

    Private Shared m_oWaitHandle_TimerHasCompleted As System.Threading.AutoResetEvent = Nothing

    Public Shared Sub Main()

        Try
            'Application Entry point ...

            'Create the global timer
            m_oTimer = New Timers.Timer
            With m_oTimer
                .AutoReset = True
                .Interval = 2000

                .Start()
            End With
            'Create the WaitHandle
            m_oWaitHandle_TimerHasCompleted = New System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(False)

            'Show your form 
            Dim oFrm As New Form1
            Application.Run(oFrm)

            'Wait for the timer to also indicate that it has finished before exiting
            m_oWaitHandle_TimerHasCompleted.WaitOne()

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Error Handling here ...
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub m_oTimer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs) Handles m_oTimer.Elapsed
        'Timer will fire here ...
        Try
            If 1 = 2 Then
                m_oWaitHandle_TimerHasCompleted.Set()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Error Handling ...
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please note that 'm_oWaitHandle_TimerHasCompleted.Set()' will never run, you'll have to add a condition ... however, once run, the WaitOne will complete and the application will exit as required.

Hows zat?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want to create a single instance of a timer, that does not need to be instantiated via a form?

If so ... Create a new class called 'Main' and copy the following into it.

```
Imports System.Timers

Public Class Main

    Private Shared WithEvents m_oTimer As Timers.Timer = Nothing

    Public Shared Sub Main()

        Try
            'Application Entry point ...

            'Create the global timer
            m_oTimer = New Timers.Timer
            With m_oTimer
                .AutoReset = True
                .Interval = 2000

                .Start()
            End With

            'Show your form 
            Dim oFrm As New Form1
            Application.Run(oFrm)

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Error Handling here ...
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub m_oTimer_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs) Handles m_oTimer.Elapsed
        'Timer will fire here ...
        Try

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Error Handling ...
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Once done, right click on your project and select 'Properties'. In the Application tab you'll see a checkbox called 'Enable Application framework'. Uncheck this box. Now, in the dropdown called 'Startup Object' you should now see 'Sub Main' .... Select that.

When the application runs, Sub Main will now run instead of your form.

This will create the Timer that will fire outside of your form. Please note, as you're not syncing it, I believe it'll run inside a thread so be a little careful there :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your proposed solutions solves one of my problem. The other problem remains the same. As mentioned in the question I want a global Timer (which you have provided) and secondly I want to wait for Timer to finish or dispose. So for example if in your proposed solution I don't initiate and run oFrm and remove the line Application.Run(oFrm) then the application will exit. What I want is that if Timer is running then application should not exit.